# Thymeleaf - enum value cannot be bind

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a problem with binding value to enum field in thymeleaf

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="${petDto.rating.finalRating}" th:value="${T(net.azurewebsites.mypet.domain.ratings.Scale).COOL}" />
```

I want to set enum value Scale.Cool to field finalRating which has type Scale.
But in this way its not working. Thymeleaf do not bind value from  th:value to th:field.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`th:field` and `th:value` cannot work together in one input. `th:field` effectively replaces value, id and the name of the input. So your input is equivalent to

```
<input type="hidden" id="rating.finalRating" name="rating.finalRating" th:value="${petDto.rating.finalRating}" />
```

To achieve what you want, just omit `th:field` from the input.

Please refer to the documentation of [thymeleaf inputs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#inputs)